# How to download Kendo UI Grid.js

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to download the minified version of kendo ui grid javascript file. From where I can download that? Also, will it be possible to download kendo javascript files without licence.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on Telerik's CDN for Kendo UI [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/cdn-service) if you own a licence and want to use their CDN instead of installing Kendo UI locally.

[Kendo UI Core you can find on GitHub](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core) and [use freely](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/LICENSE.md).

While it is certainly possible to use the CDN version of the full Kendo UI version wihtout having a licence, you shouldn't. You use the library which proves it's valuable. So, it's no different from the effort you make in your own development. You would want to get paid, wouldn't you?